# Get X-Ray interactions For AWS QLDB Using Nodejs ( lambda )

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-qldb

I tried this way, But I want more detailed requests inside QLDB x-ray interactions.

```
const AWSXRay = require("aws-xray-sdk");
/** QLDB x-ray */
AWSXRay.captureAWS(require("aws-sdk")); //For this x-ray show sendCommand() Requests, But info not in detail

AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require("https")); //For this x-ray show 'POST https://session.qldb.xx-xxx-x.amazonaws.com/', But info not in detail
/** QLDB x-ray */
```

Let me know if anyone tried in a different way apart from the above option I mentioned.

in case if you know just share your snippet code here. ( X-Ray interactions with QLDB  )

Answer (score 1):

Currently, QLDB is not integrated with AWS X-Ray. This leaves the following options to trace interactions with QLDB:

- Tracing AWS SDK calls: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-awssdkclients.html. An example here is: `AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'))`.
- Tracing calls to downstream HTTP web services: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-httpclients.html. An example here is `AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('http'))`.

These options - as you point out - do not provide much outside of identifying the operation/API invoked or the URL a request is made to. What further details are you interested in viewing in the traces? For instance, are you interested in identifying the exact commands - such as `CommitTransaction` or `ExecuteStatement` - sent through in a `SendCommand` API call? For the commands supported by the `SendCommand` API, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/API_QLDB-Session_SendCommand.html.